# Swift delegate not firing

Tags: swift, delegates, xcode7

I have a pageViewController and an itemController for the contents. Now I want to know the scrollView position of the itemController. I created a protocol and a delegate. Somehow the delegate is nog firing. Why?

My itemController:

```
protocol scrollPosDelegate{
    func scrollPosChanged(newVal:Float)
}

class PageItemController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var scrollDelegate:scrollPosDelegate? = nil
    var positie: Float = 8.0 {
         didSet {
               if let delegate = scrollDelegate{
                    delegate.scrollPosChanged(self.positie)
                    print(positie)
                    }
                }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
         scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
        positie += 0.1
    }

}
```

My pageViewController:

```
class PageView: UIViewController, scrollPosDelegate {


    func scrollPosChanged(newVal:Float){
         print("Number Changed:\(newVal)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to assign value to scrollDelegate.

By the way, instead of translating UIScrollView delegate messages, you can simply set PageView as UIScrollView delegate for PageItemController.

```
class PageView: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    // Don't forget to call!
    func setupDelegate() {
         pageItemController.scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
         print("Number Changed")
    }

}
```

Comment: I get a "Use of unresolved identifier 'pageItemController'" error.

Comment: I have a scrollView on the pageItemController and I'd to know it's position on pageView. I don't know how the scrollViewDidScroll function will help me on the pageView. Can you explain?